# R DT package button to download files does not include display tables

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

Here is the simple example.
Suppose I am looking at the table, and I want to download the table excluding the Sepal.Length column.

What should I do? I try to toggle the Sepal.Length column out, and click on excel, but it stills gives me the whole data. I don't want it. Is there any way that I can manipulate this?

Maybe I am not familiar with how it operates in the backend, after I use row reorder extension, or search/filter tables, then the downloaded files is what table displays. So I want something similar when I hide the columns.

This is useful when I have too many columns in a table and sometimes I do not need all of them.

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
      iris, extensions = "Buttons",
      options = list(dom = "Blfrtip", 
        buttons = list('copy', 'excel', 'print', 'colvis'))
    )
  }
)
```

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input$tbl_columns_selected` and `input$tbl_rows_selected`

Here you can select rows and columns (**NB : to select column click on the label below the DT**)
If you want a selection only on columns then remove `input$tbl_rows_selected` and set `target = 'column'` only

```
library(shiny)
library(xlsx)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
      DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')
      ,downloadButton("downloadData",label ="Download")
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(iris, selection = list(target = 'row+column'))

    myFilteredData <- reactive({
      df <- iris[input$tbl_rows_selected, input$tbl_columns_selected]
      if (length(input$tbl_columns_selected) == 1) {
        df <- as.data.frame(df)
        colnames(df) <- colnames(iris)[input$tbl_columns_selected]
      }
      df
    })

    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {paste("test.xlsx")},
      content = function(file) {
        write.xlsx(myFilteredData(),file, row.names=FALSE)
      })
  }
)
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you very much for your reply. I have thought about your idea to use checkBoxGroupInput to decide the table columns, but what I am looking for is actually some feature or parameters that in the DT package so that I can manipulate it in the datatable function. I still appreciate your help though.